# Connect Only Domains Domain name to Netlify

Tags: dns, netlify, netlify-cms, netlify-cli

I have registered a domain name in Only Domains website, it is provisioned,
Yet I am unable to link it to my Netlify project.

Steps I followed till now:

1. Went to Only Domains -> Domain Name -> DNS Settings
2. Clicked on: Delegate to Your Name Servers, then added 4 Host Names provided by Netlify (I did not add the IP address though, as they did not provide)

Yet, I am not able to set up a route,

If someone has registered the same, please do let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the IP address from Netlify, After you add a new domain alias in the App Domain Management you will see "Check DNS configuration", click on it, then a popup will open you can see there is an IP address, just copy it and use it in OnlyDomains with each Host Names that you add from Netlify.